# Upgrading from Altera DE2 to DE2-115

Tags: intel-fpga

I got a DE2 board that failed so they sent me a replacement board which is the finer DE2-115. But my config file (.sof) is not forward compatible. How can I migrate existing projects that I have for the DE2 to DE2-115? I think I need to define a .sof file and I don't know how to do that, it was my university instructor who gave me a public domain .sof file that works with the DE2 but not the DE2-115. I got a spec error msg saying something like pins are different from the Quartus envirronment. Can you propose or suggest what I should do?

Related question what project I want to program with this gear
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872409/how-to-make-pong-for-the-nios-ii-processors

I got C code, assembly and hardware definitions that work with the DE2 already. So I want these in DE2-115 as well instead of getting started from scratch with DE2-115 I just want to move some projects but the .sof file is incompatible beteween DE2 and DE2-115. The big difference is that DE2 uses Cyclone II while DE2-115 has Cyclone IV chip.

Comment: The answer on this thread might help as well [Using De2-115 board to run a project developed on a different board?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720508/using-de2-115-board-to-run-a-project-developed-on-a-different-board)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DE2-115-board has a different layout so the peripherals on the board are connected differently to the fpga than on the DE2-board.

I would suggest that you read up on how the external peripherals are connected (in the manual for the DE2-115-board) and change that pin mapping in Quartus. You will also have to specify the correct model of the fpga as well so that Quartus will know what part to synthesize for.