# What to change when migrating designs from Altera DE2 to DE2-115?

Tags: fpga, design, intel-fpga, alu, quartus-ii

I'm migrating a [working design](http://www.ict.kth.se/courses/IS1500/2012/dicom/index.html) from Altera DE2 to Altera DE2-115 and I'm running into problems. First everything works with DE2 just like mentioned in the exercises doing what is instructed. Now I want the designs to work also with DE2-115. So I make new designs with the chip that is for the DE2-115 (Cyclone IVE EP4CE115F29C7). But besides changing the chip to Cyclone IVE EP4CE115F29C7, I don't know what other changes to make. So I download the design (the mux4to1 mentioned in the text) to the board and it's not working. I didn't run a simulation with this project but it compiles and it's basically a copy in Quartus II of another project that was for DE2 and I just did a new project for the Cyclone IV chip and copied over the sketch. Now I wonder what I'm doing wrong since the design downloads fine in Quartus Programmer downloading to the board but the it doesn't run like it's suppossed to, the board is simply "locked". Do you have any ideas what I should do? I can provide more details if needed and I asked about this before and then the answer says that the "pin mappings differ" between DE2 and DE2-115.

[Upgrading from Altera DE2 to DE2-115](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/44584/upgrading-from-altera-de2-to-de2-115)

So can you tell me where I can find what the pin mappings are and what I should change them to?

Comment: The answer on this thread might help as well [Using De2-115 board to run a project developed on a different board?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720508/using-de2-115-board-to-run-a-project-developed-on-a-different-board)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the pin mappings in the project and update them so that you are using the "new" pins in your new project. Quartus has a GUI for this sort of thing.

I'm surprised it builds without that, but it may have just selected a random set of pins for you.

You'll need to get the pinout for the new board and decide for yourself which pins youwant to connect to which of your design signals.

**edit:**
A link to the pin mappings is available at the bottom of this page (the QSF file): http://www.altera.com/education/univ/materials/boards/de2-115/unv-de2-115-board.html